# How to update data in a embedded child element in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Its probably something small that im missing but for the life of me i cannot figure out how to update a embedded document in my mongodb. Below is the document im trying to update:

```
db.customers.insert({
_id: 'custId2',
Fname:"john" ,
Lname:"Mandel" ,
Pnum:"051-895421" ,
Mnum:"087-478512" ,

    orders: {
                    Orddate:"25-10-2015" ,
                    Ordtime:"15.50" ,
                    ProdType: "accessory",
                    Product: "USB Drive",
                    Netcost:40 ,

                },
    address:    {   
                        Billingaddress:"21 Culrua, Brown Street, Portlaw, Co.Wexford" ,
                        Deliveryaddress:"21 Culrua, Brown Street, Portlaw, Co.Waterford" 
                    }
});
```

And here is the update query im trying to do

```
db.customers.update(
{Fname: "john" },
{
$set{   
        "address.Billingaddress":"34 Vegas Street",
        "address.Deliveryaddress":"34 Vegas Street"
    }
}
);
```

But when i run it i get this error but i cannot see what im missing

```
Syntax error: Unexpected Token {
```

Comment: A colon is missing after the `$set`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your query was correct but you miss little things `:` after `$set` so query as below :

```
db.customers.update({
    "Fname": "john"
}, {
    "$set": {
        "address.Billingaddress": "34 Vegas Street",
        "address.Deliveryaddress": "34 Vegas Street"
    }
})
```

Check [mongo update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)  .